# How do I solve this limit involving arcsin?

Tags: calculus

I was reading a book on problem-solving and near the end of one of the proofs the equality $$\lim_{n \to \infty} 2^n\arcsin\left(\dfrac{1}{2^n}\right) = 1$$ was glossed over.

This was not at all obvious to me and I am having a hard time continuing on without understanding how to find this value. There do not seem to be any other posts that address this limit so any help at all, whether that be in the form of hints or of walking me through the solution, will be appreciated.

Comment: $\arcsin(x) = x + o(x)$ near $0$

Comment: If $z_n=\arcsin(1/2^n)$ then $z_n\to 0$ and $$\frac{z_n}{\sin(z_n)}\to 1.$$

Comment: $\arcsin(z) = z + \left( \frac{1}{2} \right) \frac{z^3}{3} + \left( \frac{1 \cdot 3}{2 \cdot 4} \right) \frac{z^5}{5} + \left( \frac{1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5}{2 \cdot 4 \cdot 6} \right) \frac{z^7}{7} + \cdots $

Comment: More generally, $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\arcsin(x)}x\to 1.$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your limit follows, *a fortiori*, from the fact that $$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}x\arcsin \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=1$$
Subsituting $y=1/x$, this is the same as saying $$\lim\limits_{y\to 0^+}\frac{\arcsin y}{y}=1$$
Taking reciprocals, this is the same as $$\lim\limits_{y\to 0^+}\frac{y}{\arcsin y}=1$$
And substituting $\theta=\arcsin y$, this is the same as $$\lim\limits_{\theta\to 0^+}\frac{\sin\theta}{\theta}=1$$

Answer (score 2):

The original limit is
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} 2^n\arcsin\left(\dfrac{1}{2^n}\right).\tag{1}\label{1}$$

Let's set this aside for a moment and instead consider

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} x \arcsin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right),$$
or
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\arcsin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\frac{1}{x}},$$
which is equivalent to
$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\arcsin(x)}{x}.\tag{2}\label{2}$$

We see that if this limit exists, it will equal our original limit \eqref{1}.

Both the top and bottom of \eqref{2} go to $0$, so let's try L'Hôpital's.

For $x$ in $(-1,1)$, the function $\arcsin(x)$ is differentiable, with derivative given by
$$\arcsin'(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}.$$

Returning to \eqref{2} and taking the limit of the derivatives of top and bottom, we have
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\arcsin'(x)}{1} &= \\
\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} &= \\
1.
\end{align}
Since this limit exists, it is equal to \eqref{2}, which is equal to the original limit \eqref{1}.